# Extract certain extension links from html

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have an HTML file containing many links. I need to extract all `mp4` links from the page and save the links to another file using sed/awk/grep.
The page is available offline at `page.html`.
Example: Page contains:

> `<a title="Download this file..." target="_blank" href="http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4">`

So the output file should have:

> `http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4`

Likewise, the page may contains several mp4 links.

Comment: What do you mean with "`mp4` links"? URLs ending with `.mp4`? Links with a `type` attribute containing "mp4"? URLs that contain "mp4" anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat foo.html
<a href="http://example.com/foo.mp4">foo</a>
$ tr '"' '\n' < foo.html  | grep http | grep '\.mp4$' >> mp4s
$ cat mp4s
http://example.com/foo.mp4
```

What this does:

1. `tr`anslate all doublequotes `"` to newlines `\n`
2. `grep` all lines containing `http`
3. `grep` all lines containing `.mp4` at the end of the line

Comment: This is __Awesome__ ! Could you explain how this works ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try `grep` with `PCRE` option for lookahead and behind assertions:

```
grep -oP '(?<=href=")[^"]+.mp4(?=")' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
<a title="Download this file..." target="_blank" href="http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4">
```

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=href=")[^"]+.mp4(?=")' file
http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way to get the `url` out of a long string using `awk`:

```
awk -F"http://" '/mp4/ {split($2,a,"\"");print FS a[1]}' file
http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4
```

Using `gnu awk`

```
awk -v RS="http://" -F\" 'NR>1 && /mp4/ {print RS $1}' file
http://webaddress.domain.org/videos/sometext/file_name_12.mp4
```

Comment: OP only needs `mp4 urls`, so probably the solution needs to filter the rest.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(http[^>]\+\.mp4\).*/\1/p' your_offline.html > allmp4_links.txt
```